# How to skip first N elements with CSS or jQuery?

Tags: jquery, html, css, css-selectors

I know the CSS "child" methods, but these methods only work for a single div or for divs with same settings and not for a group.

I want to run a script from div #7 till the last one. The problem is that all divs have the same structure (which is a requirement).

Example:

```
<div class"my_div">Some Text</div>
<div class"my_div">Some Text</div>
<div class"my_div">Some Text</div>
<div class"my_div">Some Text</div>
<div class"my_div">Some Text</div>
<div class"my_div">Some Text</div>
<div class"my_div">Some Text</div> <!-- from this point on all divs should have a certain style applied -->
<div class"my_div">Some Text</div>
<div class"my_div">Some Text</div>
<!-- ... -->
<div class"my_div">Some Text</div>
```

Is there a way to say something like `.my_div:eq(7-999)`?

Comment: _“Is there a way to say something like `.my_div:eq(7-999)`?”_ – http://alistapart.com/article/quantity-queries-for-css has some interesting approaches on doing stuff like this, basically by combining different pseudo classes.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use jQuery's [**slice**](http://api.jquery.com/slice/) method:

```
$('.my_div').slice(6)
```

A pure CSS approach is the [**nth-child**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/%3Anth-child) selector:

```
.my_div:nth-child(n+6)
```

It seems to be supported by modern browsers: http://caniuse.com/#feat=css-sel3

Comment: Thx for support! Also really simple and absolute what I was looking for!

Answer (score 2):

Just try with following [`:gt()`](https://api.jquery.com/gt-selector/) selector:

```
.my_div:gt(6)
```

Comment: Thx for support! - so simple, and it works! But I decide me for the "slice" methode, because its more comfortable for my case. But Thx!!

Comment: `:gt()` and `;lt()` are deprecated

Answer (score 0):

```
.my_div:nth-last-child(6) ~ .my_div {
  attribute: value
}
```

This selector will match any `.my_div` item after the sixth.
You can change the number to anything you like.

The only thing you can't do now is telling the selector when to stop.
That would require a second one:

```
.my_div:nth-last-child(x) {
  attribute: value
}
```

Here X has to match the number when you want to stop counting.

To make things a bit easier, you could also just use this:

```
.my_div:nth-child(n+6) {
  attribute: value
}
```

which will also count all elements after the 6th till infinity.

Here a link to an article explaining the method in all detail: http://alistapart.com/article/quantity-queries-for-css
(esp. this section: http://alistapart.com/article/quantity-queries-for-css#section6 )

Comment: `:nth-child(n+6)` would INCLUDE the 6th child, not skip it as the answer suggests.

Answer (score 0):

Yo can use below code for range selection like element's having index greater than 6 and less than 10:

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
     
  $(".my_div:lt(10)").filter(":gt(6)").addClass("blue");
  
});
```

```css
.blue{
  color: blue;
  }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="my_div">Some Text</div>
<div class="my_div">Some Text</div>
<div class="my_div">Some Text</div>
<div class="my_div">Some Text</div>
<div class="my_div">Some Text</div>
<div class="my_div">Some Text</div>
<div class="my_div">Some Text</div> 
<div class="my_div">Some Text</div>
<div class="my_div">Some Text</div>
<div class="my_div">Some Text</div>
<div class="my_div">Some Text</div>
<div class="my_div">Some Text</div>
<div class="my_div">Some Text</div> 
<div class="my_div">Some Text</div>
<div class="my_div">Some Text</div>
<div class="my_div">Some Text</div>
<div class="my_div">Some Text</div>
<div class="my_div">Some Text</div>
<div class="my_div">Some Text</div> 
<div class="my_div">Some Text</div>
<div class="my_div">Some Text</div>
```